# wcf basic authentication request to display the wsdl

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I am using UserNamePasswordValidator for consumption of wcf service, however would like to display the wsdl only to authenticated users, I would like to implement Basic authentication to then validate the User and Password and show the wsdl the service, through https, how could I do that? I am using basicHttpBinding, need interoperability with other languages.

Comment: You would probably have to do a lot of work to add username/password validation to protect the WSDL.  A simpler solution is to simply disable metadata publishing by the service and provide a copy of the WSDL to clients that need it.  They can generate a proxy from a WSDL file as easily as they can from a metadata endpoint.

Comment: Another option would be to configure the application on the server (for example, the IIS Application that host the WCF server) to require credentials of some sort to even access the application.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733114(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i like to do something programmatically, leave that responsibility with the service and not the web server (iis) because added a wcf service in a MVC application, only to host a website.
the first option would work, but would like something automated, for example, create a controller to return the service wsdl, and authenticate through ActionFilterAttribute.

Comment: would be perfect, you can use something like actionfiterattribute the MVC framework with wcf services.